Upgrading to andt 5.20.0 - ERROR in ./node_modules/@ant-design/fast-color/lib/FastColor.js 56:10
I recently upgraded to the latest version of antd@5.20.0, I used npm i antd --save --legacy-peer-deps and it worked fine. However, when I run npm start the console is complaining with the below error. Anybody else facing this issue?
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ant-design/fast-color/lib/FastColor.js 56:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (56:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|    * All FastColor objects are valid. So isValid is always true. This property is kept to be compatible with TinyColor.
|    */
>   isValid = true;
|
|   /**
 @ ./node_modules/@ant-design/fast-color/lib/index.js 6:17-39
 @ ./node_modules/@rc-component/color-picker/lib/color.js
 @ ./node_modules/@rc-component/color-picker/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/color-picker/util.js
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/color-picker/ColorPicker.js
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/color-picker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/index.js
 @ ./app/containers/AdminLitePortal/components/CrisisManagementPortalV2/IncidentDetailsV2/IncidentDetailsV2.tsx
 @ ./app/containers/App/index.js
 @ ./app/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true ./app/app.js


I tried clearing npm cache, removing node_modules, and reinstalling. Which didn't work, so I also tried running npm uninstall antd and reinstalled it, still got the same error.

I also had the same problem yesterday, but it seems to be no longer erroring anymore, you can yarn or npm install again

You're right, I uninstalled and installed again with "npm i antd --save --legacy-peer-deps" and it works. This was committed yesterday to fast-color https://github.com/ant-design/fast-color/commit/8f8748632a9f4e9f250105b263247532e1dba609, maybe that is what fixed it.
